# Css column layout - inline block elements, what is percent width relative to?

Tags: css

I'm not sure I understand how css column layout is supposed to work.

I have a straightforward html

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
```

and css

```
.block {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50em;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
}
```

This works as expected with the elements flowing downwards and then over into a second column.

Now what if I change the width value of `.block` [to a percentage width](http://jsbin.com/OXeKEsU/5/edit?css,output)? All my widths are tiny. They still are clearly relative to something since shrinking and growing the percentages changes the width proportionately but I have no idea what 100% corresponds to.

What is the percentage width relative to?

Comment: Percentage width is relative to width of the parent element.

Comment: Click that second link @PawełDuda it clearly is not in this case

Comment: My bad! Did not see the link. Anyway, perhaps the problem is related to the nested inline-blocks? If you change display to "inline-table" for .container, it appears to work just fine.

Comment: column-count: 2; doesn't actually set a width for the element. It just tells the web browser to split this element into 2 equal parts (I think, I don't use column-count so I may be mistaken.

Assign the parent a width:100px; and the children will inherit that width when they try to become 30% of it.

Comment: Important caveat: As of this writing, column-count is largely unsupported, and should be avoided, unless you're coding for a closed environment with a controlled browser/version list. http://caniuse.com/multicolumn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width is relative to the column pseudo-element inserted by the browser:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/

> In the traditional CSS box model, the content of an element is flowed into the content box of the corresponding element. Multi-column layout **introduces a new type of container between the content box and the content, namely the column box** (or column for short). The content of a multicol element is flowed into its column boxes.

(Emphasis mine.)

So, the percentage width you're asking for is relative to the implicit column boxes.

## Browser Support

As I noted in my comment support for column-count etc is poor today. Except where you really need a specific feature of CSS multicolumn, I find it easier to just use the old inline-block approach. Works in every browser in use today, easy to figure out.

http://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/nt83M/

```
.block {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 45%;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

<span class=container>
<span class=block></span>
<span class=block></span>
<span class=block></span>
<span class=block></span>
<span class=block></span>
</span>
```

Two important caveats:

For old IE support to work properly you need to use tags that are inline by default, like span. Using a tag that's block by default, like div, will look great in Chrome etc but fail in IE8.

You need to set vertical-align: top in the inner tags to get things to work the way you'd expect them (otherwise everything acts like vertical-align: bottom).

Answer (score 1):

Essentially how column layouts work is you have a container that a width and you split that container into columns. When you decide how many columns you want for your design you assign each of those columns a percentage. Then you float those columns next to each other.

So if you have a 12 column layout the column classes would be as follows:

```
.col-1 { width: 4.8076923077% }
.col-2 { width: 13.4615384615% }
.col-3 { width: 22.1153846154% }
.col-4 { width: 30.7692307692% }
.col-5 { width: 39.4230769231% }
.col-6 { width: 48.0769230769% }
.col-7 { width: 56.7307692308% }
.col-8 { width: 65.3846153846% }
.col-9 { width: 74.0384615385% }
.col-10 { width: 82.6923076923% }
.col-11 { width: 91.3461538462% }
.col-12 { width: 100%; margin: 0 }
```

The above columns take into account margins and padding, [but here's a fiddle that lays it out.](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/j4GZJ/)

Answer (score 1):

Parent element width within a content column refers to the column width, a property that defaults to `auto`. A columnar element is either defined by `column-width` or `column-count` (but not both, `column-count` overrides any `column-width` value if they are both non-auto). So in your example, providing `column-count` is causing an automatically generated width to be presented as container width.

source - right above example IX here: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/CR-css3-multicol-20110412/

> Column boxes act as the containing block for their content. That is,
>   column boxes behave like block-level, table cell, and inline-block
>   boxes as per CSS 2.1, section 10.1, item 2 [CSS21]. However, column
>   boxes do not establish containing blocks for elements with ‘position:
>   fixed’ or ‘position: absolute’.